# Appcompatv7 - v21 Navigation drawer not showing hamburger icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-navigation

I am implementing the lollipop style navigation drawer with latest appcompat support library but the problem is the hamburger icon is never displayed . Only back icon is shown.

This is my activity code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    initViews();
}


private void initViews(){

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,toolbar ,  R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) { 

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */ 
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        } 

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */ 
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        } 
    }; 


    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener 
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 

 }
}
```

This is my styles file

```
 <resources>
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Test" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/Theme.Test.DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Test.DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

The layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Navigation Drawer Showing Back Button]

[image: Navigation Drawer Showing Back Button]

In both cases only back arrow is shown , i have read many posts but nothing seems to make a difference . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You need to call

```
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Where do you call this?

Comment: I guess inside onDrawerClosed() and onDrawerOpened()

Comment: Just after you initialize your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

Comment: Hi! Can we show Hamburger icon it without calling `mDrawerToggl.syncState()`, actually i am showing the Navigation drawer as overlay on the ToolBar so the animation is not required in my case.

Comment: No joke, been trying to find this for two days. THANKS!

Comment: Thank you very much @Pedro Oliveira. It finally helped me out.

Comment: The maybe your problem is another one @AlexVPerl. No need to downvote just because it didn't work for you. Hell, if I'm gonna downvote all the answers that doesn't work for me....

Comment: @PedroOliveira Is that not the use-case for up / down vote buttons?

Comment: No, not at all. Here's some help. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: I'm happy for you that know how to use the website and make it better :)

Comment: Is there any way to show drawer toggle icon in `NavigationView`?

Comment: What is the purpose of "syncState"  ? I see it being called multiple times in samples...

Comment: i did everything and hamburger icon show in higher api but it is not working in api 14 @PedroOliveira can you help?

Answer (score 19):

Make sure that you're importing the correct drawer toggle.

When I imported the v4 version I had the arrow (below).

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Changing it to this (below, v7) fixed my issue.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that you call

`mDrawerToggle.syncState();`

AFTER calling

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: is it possible without setting the toolbar as actionbar, to show the hamburger drawable?

Answer (score 13):

When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: And `onOptionsItemSelected` too.

Comment: Not help for me. Android 6.0

Answer (score 9):

Since my NavigationDrawer was extending a Fragment not an Activity I was not able to override postCreate. The below is what I did.

```
   ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // this sets the button to the    back icon
   actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); // makes it clickable
   actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);// set your own icon
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe expand a little about why you think this would help the person asking?

Comment: Sorry they wanted the hamburger icon displayed and the way I changed it was with the above code. Please read the comments beside the code. This could help people who get stuck with the back icon on the navigation drawer.

Comment: How would you show the hamburger drawable in the toolbar, without making toolbar as actionbar ?

Answer (score 6):

Dont forget to override onOptionsItemSelected method and check if ctionBarDrawerToggle was clicked, in this case return true otherwise the activity will be finished.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: One-liner: `return actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use this:

```
// Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    }
});
```

Comment: remove code after *mDrawerToggle.syncState()*, and you good to go.

Answer (score 3):

While including ActionBarDrawerToggle, make sure to use the post method:

```
mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       mDrawerToggle.syncState();
   }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me! That and also removing a workaround done by using `setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu/ic_back)` that was forcing the icon that was pretended when switching between fragment.
But after being updated to the new animated burger icon, that does not do the job.

Answer (score 3):

`mDrawerToggle.syncState()` did not work for me, but I eventually got it to work with:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger_icon);
```

I was, however, not using a Toolbar.

Comment: This line of code saved my day. I have converted my eclipse code to android studio and all of a sudden my drawer toggle button automatically converted to arrow. now it is working fine after adding this line of code. Thanks a lot @john Leehey

Answer (score 3):

I also got similar problem, in my case problem was,
when initiating actionbartoggle, 
I was not passing valid toolbar argument (toolbar was initialized later), 
without a proper, non-null toolbar, ActionBarToggle will fail to create a hamburger icon.

```
actionBarToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, 
R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can call syncState() from your Activity's onPostCreate to synchronize the indicator with the state of the linked DrawerLayout after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

Also ActionBarDrawerToggle can be used directly as a DrawerLayout.DrawerListener, or if you are already providing your own listener, call through to each of the listener methods from your own.

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  .
  .
  .
  .
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I have extended AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.

```
mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,null, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        if( getSupportActionBar()!= null)
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_opened);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_closed);
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drawer was not showing when clicking action bar menu. This fixed it for me.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
      //add your switch statement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```