# Toolbar Navigation Hamburger Icon missing

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm looking for a way to display the hamburger icon whitout using the Drawer/DrawerToggle and use the default icon included in Android
[image]

By setting `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` it display the back arrow but not the hambuerger. Other post on Stackoverflow (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525229/toolbar-navigation-icon-never-set) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon)) use the DrawerLayout or a custom drawable. I cannot find the vector or png for the hamburger icon on the Android source.

**Do you know how can I find the original hamburger icon in android/support library?** (or how to displayed it)

*Note:  Vector and png can be found on google.com/design website :* http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#

In my activity

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "navigation clicked");
    }
});
```

Layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
```

Styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">


    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDef</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkDef</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryDef</item>

    <!-- Remove the actionbar shadow-->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appcompatv7 - v21 Navigation drawer not showing hamburger icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon)

Comment: @PedroOliveira it's not a duplicate because I explcitly sayed I didn't use ActionBarDrawerToggle

Comment: Then if you're not using a drawer how are you supposed to show a menu? That hamburger icon is part of the drawer.

Comment: @PedroOliveira this is not the main question, but it is not used to show a manu. I know it's against the UX Guidlines and it will not be in a public app. The question is just to find the icon inside Android if it's possible.

Comment: @ASP this do not answer the question

Comment: These are some of the times when I really hate android, simple things like this that can easily be done in other languages/platforms and you need to write all these lines of code for it -__-

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to use the same drawer as lollipop then let me tell you that's not a static image. That image is drawn in real time by a class called `DrawerArrowDrawableToggle`. So there is no "hamburger" icon for that.

However if you want the hamburger icon with no animation you can find it here:

https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=menu&style=baseline

[image]

Comment: Your answer complete 50% of the question, thank you ! 
Do you know a way to implement this for pre-lolipop device ?

Comment: If you want to achive that nice animation with the hamburger menu I suggest you look up appcompatv7 for that and set up a drawer menu. If you want to just show the menu icon then just place the image inside the drawables and use it. I will post here my repo with a nice and simple template on "Material Drawer" that works on pre-lollipop devices :) https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template

Comment: thank you, can you comlete your answer to include http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components where we can also find official icons. Not that vector icon requires API 21, so we have to use png

Comment: Friend on that site you just have to click "Download ZIP" and it will download all the png's with the same drawable folder structure android project uses :) Just go there. Select your favorite color, click download zip, and drag that "res" folder into your own "res" folder :)

Comment: Thanks but it was just to compelte your answer with alternative method

Comment: Edited. Does that do the job? :)

Answer (score 39):

To have an animated hamburger icon you should use `DrawerLayout` with `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and enable the icon for the `ActionBar` and for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Example:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null)
{
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.hello_world, R.string.hello_world)
   {

      public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
      {
         supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         //drawerOpened = false;
      }

      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
      {
         supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         //drawerOpened = true;
      }
   };
   mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
   drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
   mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Also, you need to add these methods to your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work indeed... until I realized the missing drawerLayout.syncState to make the hamburger icon appear :)

Comment: @ptitvinou, see updated answer. I add missing methods.

Comment: @mohax how can I just show hamburguer icon instead of back arrow?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini, this line do it `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);`. If you pass `false` as argument you'll see backArrow. Do not forget to add 2 methods from end of answer to activities class'

Comment: @mohax I'm still seeing the arrow icon instead of the home, this activity is not the initial one, this could be a problem?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini, this code works for me, so if you have some problem with it you could ask a separate question and give a link to this answer in it. Need to see yours code to find a problem.

Comment: @mohax I need to add this line: mDrawerToggle.syncState(); after drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

Comment: how can move animated hamburger icon to right of Toolbar.

Comment: @Kenji, I think you can't do it with standart widget. May be you could try to find some library for it

Comment: This code worked perfectly for me, but when I switch views the hamburger icon disappears. I have a separate include, however the icon appears for one layout and not the other.

Answer (score 30):

For that you just need write to some lines

```
   DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
   drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
   toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
   toggle.syncState();
```

**toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);**  if this is false make it true or remove this line

Comment: I am not able to understand one thing. If the main functionality of that hamburger icon is to open the drawer then why do we need to add drawlistener to it separately?

Answer (score 17):

You can try to make your own drawable for the hamburger icon like this.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2L3,16v2zM3,13h18v-2L3,11v2zM3,6v2h18L21,6L3,6z" />
</vector>
```

Then in your fragment/activity,

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.as_above);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

For other drawables, this might help: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-anydpi-v21/

Answer (score 15):

Here is the simplest solution that worked for me.

The `ActionBarDrawerToggle` has two types constructors. One of them take **toolbar** as a parameter. Use that (second one below) to get the *animated* hamburger.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.content_desc_drawer_open, 
R.string.content_desc_drawer_close);

ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.content_desc_drawer_open, 
R.string.content_desc_drawer_close);`  //use this constructor
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I found the simplest solution here:

[appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon)

All I had to do was to call:

```
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. 
Get the `ToolBar` and then set Navigation icon

```
final android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.blablabla);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle("title");
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_list);
```

Answer (score 5):

ok to hide back arrow use

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

then find hamburger icon in web ->[hamburger](https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png)

and finally, set this drawable in your project with action bar method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.hamburger_icon);
```

Comment: I'm searching the hamburger icon in the support lib or android sdk.

Comment: @AlexPerl perhaps you are doing something wrong. Can you tell me about your case.

Answer (score 4):

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

it's work with me

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this, but you will lose animation between arrow and hamburger icon

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_drawer_left);

_drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            changeDrawerIconOnDrawerClick(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            changeDrawerIconOnDrawerClick(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        }
    };

     //to change default icon to hamburger item initially
    changeDrawerIconOnDrawerClick(R.drawable.ic_drawer);    }



private void changeDrawerIconOnDrawerClick(int resourceId) {
    //Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), resourceId);
    Drawable icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), resourceId, null);
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    _drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    _drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(icon);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the default Up-arrow with your own drawable

`getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger);`

Answer (score 2):

Just Add the following in your onCreate method,

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawer, mToolbar, R.string.home_navigation_drawer_open, R.string.home_navigation_drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }
        };
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

and In strings.xml,

```
<string name="home_navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="home_navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this constructor in MyActionBarDrawerToggle :

```
    public MyActionBarDrawerToggle(AppCompatActivity host, DrawerLayout drawerlayout, SupportToolbar toolbar, int openedResource, int closedResource)
        : base(host, drawerlayout, toolbar, openedResource, closedResource)
    {
        mHostActivity = host;
        mOpenedResource = openedResource;
        mClosedResource = closedResource;
    }
```

and Call this method in teh mainActivity (Using AppCompatActivity)

```
        mDrawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                           //Host Activity
            mDrawerLayout,                  //DrawerLayout
            mToolbar,                       //Toolbar
            Resource.String.openDrawer,     //Opened Message
            Resource.String.closeDrawer     //Closed Message
        );


        mDrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = true;
        mDrawerToggle.SyncState();
```

Answer (score 1):

in `onCreate()`:

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);


    drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Backstack.get(MainActivity.this).goBack();
        }
    });
    //actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And when setting up UP navigation:

```
private void setupViewsForKey(Key key) {
    if(key.shouldShowUp()) {
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }
    drawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: I can't believe this took more than an hour... thank you to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33867836/2413303

Answer (score 0):

in JetPack it work for me

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(vb.toolbar, nav)
vb.toolbar.navigationIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.icon_home, null)
```

Comment: what is vb in your case here? could you provide entire method/class?

Comment: `vb` it's my viewbinding