# Can't add navigation icon to activity

Tags: java, android

```
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
    {
        DrawerLayout fullView = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
        FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) fullView.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
        super.setContentView(fullView);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null)
        {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
            {

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
                {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    //drawerOpened = false;
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    //drawerOpened = true;
                }
            };
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add navigation drawer icon to this navigation drawer activity. now i have edited code but still now error app stops at startup

Comment: Navigation arrow icon or the hamburger icon?

Comment: hamburger icon. because its the drawer activity i need to extend this activty to all other activity

Comment: Have you had a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/28071763/7743702

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION:                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arun4fms.myapplication/com.example.arun4fms.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: You named your DrawerLayout as fullView instead of drawerLayout

Comment: ok its ok thats a lot now shows. setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)' is deprecated

Comment: `addDrawerListener()` instead.

Comment: how to add a listerner to items in drawer

Comment: `drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);`

Comment: i added this but i dosent know how to add listner

Comment: Check the rest of code from above answer. You need to override two more functions.

Comment: can u help me with code

Comment: i cant get answer from that

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try to add it to layout file modifying the xml code,or follow this tutorial for more information [Android Sliding Menu](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: so if you open the drawer you can make the icon visible or gone in code