# ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState Doesn't show the hamburger icon?

Tags: android

**UPDATE:** I have found the hamburger icon from google's github (https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_white_48dp.png) but passing the drawable resource to the ActionBarDrawerToggle and calling syncState doesn't show the hamburger icon contrary to other post's suggestions ([Appcompatv7 - v21 Navigation drawer not showing hamburger icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon))

**OLD QUESTION:** I was making a navigation bar for my android app and I realized that the hamburger icon was missing. I followed this question ([Appcompatv7 - v21 Navigation drawer not showing hamburger icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon)) and realized that I must call a `mDrawerToggle.syncState();`... Now to create an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`class I need the following:

- activity -    The Activity hosting the drawer
- drawerLayout - The DrawerLayout to link to the given Activity's ActionBar
- drawerImageRes -  A Drawable resource to use as the drawer indicator
- openDrawerContentDescRes -    A String resource to describe the "open drawer" - action for accessibility
- closeDrawerContentDescRes -   A String resource to describe the "close drawer" action for accessibility

I passed in `this` as the activity (I'm calling this from my main activity), drawerLayout as my actual drawer layout and the docs weren't really explaining what the last two params do so I just created some placeholder string resources and passed them in. But I do understand that the drawerImageRes is required to show the hamburger icon, I just don't know where to get it form..

Can anyone tell me where I can get the hamburger icon?

**EDIT:**
I figured out that the android example from https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html uses `R.drawable.ic_drawer` but I don't know where it's come from... The android developer website also says:

> The standard navigation drawer icon is available in the Download the Action Bar Icon Pack.

But I downloaded the pack and the lollipop hamburger isn't there...

Comment: Instead of the hamburger I found the 3 vertical dots. Is that an option?

Comment: No, I really want to use the hamburger that almost every other lollipop optimized android app uses.. Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 2):

If you update your support library to v22, and

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
```

do something similar to this, the hamburger icon will show up. I had a problem similar to this but now it's fixed thanks to a really helpful person.

Comment: Awesome! Thats works for me. I have to update the package from `v4` to `v7` and then i get the right contructor.

Comment: That worked for me, Android Studio's wizard provide an obsolete code with an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` from `appcompatv4`. I just have to change the import to `v7` and the constructor.