# Navigation drawer hamburguer icon doesn't show until swipe drawer manually

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I did some searchs and tried a lot of solutions, but i'm going to the same problem:

The drawer hamburguer icon doesn't show until I swipe the drawer.

[image]

Here my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setupDrawer();
    ...
}

//calling the method bellow inside onCreate
public void setupDrawer(){
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            syncState();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            syncState();
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    ActionBar actionBar =  getActionBar();

    if(actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

I want it aways showing.

Comment: You should use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` (which probably returns `null`).

Comment: @Kernald yes it works, now show the icon, and probably will not cause nullpointer exception.

Comment: Great, I posted a more detailed explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get action bar by **getSupportActionBar()** method, not **getActionBar()**. Inside your **setupDrawer()** method:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
// here
//ActionBar actionBar =  getActionBar();
ActionBar actionBar =  getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using a `Toolbar`, and probably an `ActionBarActivity`, you don't have a built-in `ActionBar`. The `ActionBarActivity` provides a wrapper around the `Toolbar` exposing usual `ActionBar` methods (like `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean enabled)`). But to get this wrapper, you have to call `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

In your code, it simply translates to this:

```
public void setupDrawer(){
    // ...

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    ActionBar actionBar =  getSupportActionBar();

    if(actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it show the back arrow and I want to show the hamburguer icon, but i fixed it using this solution > http://stackoverflow.com/a/28136349/1879661, but not sure if is the best solution, what you think?

Answer (score 0):

After fixed it from @BahodirovMirjalol solution:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
ActionBar actionBar =  getSupportActionBar();
```

I got another problem because *navigation back icon show instead hamburguer*, so I added this two methods above my `onCreate` method and it works:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136349/1879661)