# Return to previous fragment from other activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I have a simple problem. 
My problem is that I have two activities:

- Activity A
- Activity B

In **Activity A** I display 4-5 fragments. That is the main activity (Navigation Drawer) so I display 4-5 fragments in it.

From all fragments it redirects to **Activity B**.

But I want to display the last opened fragment when I come back from **Activity B**.

Now it directly opens the first fragment, which is the default. I want to open the last opened fragment when the user returns to the first activity.

Please help me...

Comment: check this ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon?rq=1

Comment: Could you please provide part of code where your first activity initialises and opens default fragment (I assume it is your onCreate method in Activity A)? Thank you.

Comment: mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            Home homeFragment = new Home();
            homeFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment, "HOME").commit();
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

Comment: this is how i initilize default fragement in oncreate

Comment: Could you please pase it in your question for more readability?

Comment: wait i will edit question

Comment: Sir please help me sir

Comment: @Aaaaaa1212 did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your first activity changes with the second one, then fragments of the former activity will destroy themself because of the activity lifecycle.

You should just open first activity using `startActivity` and store the last active fragment before it goes the letter activity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use finish while call second activity. For exp: `

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
 startActivity(i);
 //finish(); `
```

Comment: I didnt Used finish();

Comment: Wrong answer. You have to consider the activity lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSaveInstanceState` in **Activity A** to save information about last opened fragment and `onRestoreInstanceState`/`onCreate` to restore this information. For example:

```
private static final String LAST_OPENED_FRAGMENT_REF = "LAST_OPENED_FRAGMENT_REF";
private static final int HOME_FRAGMENT = 0;
private static final int OTHER_FRAGMENT = 1;

private int currentOpenedFragment = HOME_FRAGMENT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentOpenedFragment = savedInstanceState.getInt(LAST_OPENED_FRAGMENT_REF);
    }
    if (navigationView != null) {
        Fragment fragment = initFragmentByType(currentOpenedFragment);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit();
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(LAST_OPENED_FRAGMENT_REF, currentOpenedFragment);
}

private Fragment initFragmentByType(int type) {
    switch(type) {
        case HOME_FRAGMENT: return new Home();
        case OTHER_FRAGMENT: return new Other();
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no type: " + type);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to update `currentOpenedFragment` field in `onNavigationItemSelected` callback.